# Reuse patterns in sparse matrix-matrix product with Eigen lilbrary

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen, eigen3, blas

I am new to numerical computing and have some questions about pattern reusing in sparse operations.

I have two **sparse matrices** `A` and `B`, whose **non-zero-patterns never change**.

I want to compute `C=A*B` in this way (with C++ and [Eigen3.4 sparse manipulations](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html)):

```cpp
Eigen::SparseMatrix<double> A, B, C;
// init A and B
while (/* something */) {
    // update A and B, but non-zero patterns never change
    C = A * B;
    // use C
}
```

For `A,B,C`, we can assume `N=10000~90000` and `5` non-zero entries in every row.

Here is my question:

The non-zero pattern of `C` should never change, so is there any way to exploit this property?

I don't want the actual implement be like:

1. Allocate memory for `A*B`,
2. Copy `A*B` to `C` (or redirect the pointer of `C` to `A*B`).

This is obviously not optimal. Ideally, values can be directly written to `C` and no memory allocation or moving is needed.

If Eigen cannot, can other BLAS libraries exploit invariant patterns?

Sorry but I cannot find related discussions in Eigen's doc.
[This problem could be avoided by `.noalias`, which is however for dense matrix.](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TopicAliasing.html)
Any advice could be helpful. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your question is unclear to me.  Are you asking what algorithm Eigen uses to perform the operations you describe?  Or are you asking if Eigen allocates a bunch of memory and is needlessly slow for spare matrices?  The answer to the first is look at the source code.  The answer to the second is to try it and see if memory usage is high.